# jquery ajax timeout and failure

Tags: ajax, post, get, timeout

http://www.debrucellc.com/spot3/

I'm currently in China,
my server is based in the US,

for the above website, when I try to remove and create new jobs in the 
basic CRUD layout, I'm getting quite a few timeouts, and sometimes just failures,

can anyone tell me if they are getting the same issue from the US/ a different location,
also is there any way to resolve these Ajax timeouts, is this a PHP/CODING/DATABASE issue,
or is it something else

Answer (score 0):

I tried to remove a JOB it was fine but with adding I Had troubles but no time out(Cyprus).
Ok I added a Job but it taking to Much time.

Comment: so adding a job is slow when you click save?

Comment: Yes is slow but I dont get Timeout!

Comment: I loaded the site on to jelastic at http://env-3131129.jelastic.servint.net/test/spot3/#    and I'm not getting any time outs etc, but still trying to figure out if this is a us/china issue